# Impact of Wisdom: More Knowledgeable Society?

Tags: society, magic

This is a follow-up to [Impact of Dexterity: More Organized Society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/194686/impact-of-dexterity-more-organized-society) and focuses on a property called Wisdom. Wisdom determines the capacity for and ease of spellcasting and the maximum complexity of the spells you can cast.

For example, a mind-control spell. The most common mind-control spell sends magic into a target's brain, binding and altering the brain structure to cause a reward/loss effect: when the target obeys a command, the magic stimulates the dopamine center of the brain and causes an opposite effect upon the target disobeying a command.

This spell *should* require renewal, but it draws energy from the target itself (converting heat energy into mana) in order to A) conceal the effect from people checking the target for mind control, B) change the target's brain structure to reinforce the desired effect, and C) to keep the enchantment ongoing. The end result is an addiction to obedience, obedience to the caster.

However, this spell is so complex only someone with high, *very* high, Wisdom can even *think* of casting it (and very few people even know of it, it's lost knowledge because wise ancestors said "nay" to the potential of mind-control). Wisdom also determines how good someone is at spellcasting (AKA the efficiency with which one draws upon their mana and uses it to cause a magical effect) and how well someone can improvise with a spell; firing a giant ice lance is one thing, but firing seven ice lances at once, at seven separate (and quite possibly *moving*) targets is quite another.

Okay, now that the background's set, here's the deal: Wisdom is determined by three things, intelligence, intuition/perception (one's capacity to understand and be aware of what's around them), and amount of knowledge. Savants, scientists, polymaths, and mature children (think Matilda, the titular character of the book by Roald Dahl) have higher Wisdom than average.

Therefore, anyone can increase their mage abilities by A) studying and B) being more aware of their environment/people around them. Since magic is pretty dang useful (think magic from the *Harry Potter* series, then think of all the things you can do with magic that you *can't* do, or can't do as easily, with science) I am assuming everyone will act to improve their wisdom.

Simply put, **Would Wisdom Create a Wiser Society?**

**Specifically,** I'm looking for the impact Wisdom will have on education, individual's awareness of what's around them, and intelligence in general. **Will the result be a wiser society or not?**

As always, I appreciate your feedback and input, thank you for your help!

Comment: Attention Downvoters: If there is a problem, I can't fix it if I don't know what it is. Please do not downvote without an explanation!

Comment: "external (outer) awareness" - it's not clear what this means (to me at least). The question as written is hugely broad. You possibly seem to be asking would wisdom (as you've defined it) be likely to make those lacking it less likely to pass on their genetic material?? Or would "wise" people be able to have the capacity to have more than the usual number of children expected - and pass on their trait?? It's broad and fuzzy as written. You can edit to clear-up what the actual question is.

Comment: Thank you @Tantalus'touch., I will edit to clarify now.

Comment: It's not much, but I hope it helps.....by outer awareness, I mean awareness of what's around you. In my experience, people naturally focus on themselves and have only peripheral awareness of the people and surroundings around them. In general, I'd say people aren't paying much attention to what's outside their self.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of things stay the same.

With or without magic, being learned is good. The big difference is you now have an easy way to prove how much you’ve learned. Blast off a dozen different spells and you don’t have to take the SATs.

As for a spell that addicts people to obedience, we have that already. Combine charisma with disinformation and you can create memes aplenty that convince people they don’t have to do anything they don’t like regardless of what anyone else says.

People are willing to do a lot of work, and can even become violent, when defending their right to do nothing. All you have to give them is the right excuse.

All your spell adds is the ability to do that secretly. Which I suppose is something. Troll farms can be expensive.

If the mind control spell can compromise people of trust you can save on prostitutes, blackmail, and bribes. But compromising people isn’t new and taking it this far guarantees they will eventually figure out who you are. Magic or no magic. Why? Because this rout isn’t subtle.