# Will's Impact On Mages

Tags: society, magic

This is the last question in my Stats Magic series, and it was preceded by [Impact of Wisdom: More Knowledgeable Society?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/194998/impact-of-wisdom-more-knowledgeable-society). This time, the focus is on a property called Will.

Will determines how much Mana you have, your passive interference resistance, and the maximum range and power of spells.

Two things determine Will: willpower (conviction) and perseverance. Both of these can be increased with effort, so it makes sense that serious mages would want to increase their Will, since you can do more with more Mana. So, my question is, **What will be Will's Impact on Mages?**

*Things to Consider:*

1. This is a society like modern-day America, but with the recent addition of magic. Like cellphones, it's relatively new but almost everyone is used to it by now. The idea is that tech people (mages) will *want* more advanced technology (greater capacity to do magic) and invest into it.
2. More mana=greater capacity to cast and sustain spells. By this logic, every Mage should invest in Will. However, considering the other questions of this type I've posted ([Impact of Agility: Effect On Society?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/194825/impact-of-agility-effect-on-society?noredirect=1#comment604063_194825), [Impact of Dexterity: More Organized Society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/194686/impact-of-dexterity-more-organized-society), and [Increasing Impact: Fitter Society?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/194622/increasing-impact-fitter-society?noredirect=1&lq=1)) **would Will really be all that useful?**

If more details are needed, or if there's a problem with my question, please let me know, I really do appreciate your feedback and input. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "What Impact Will Will Have On Society?", as I'm sure you know questions of the type  "What Impact Will X Have On Society?" are considered too broad and off topic. It also comes out as opinion-based as there is no specific metric that can be objectively applied.

Comment: @Tantalus'touch., thank you again. I just edited, is the question clearer now?

Comment: Also in the title

Comment: Most people **do not** "want to upgrade [their cell phone] as much as they can". Most people do not actually care all that much about how great, new and shiny their cell phone is or isn't. As long as it works, it works; and when it stops working, most people will just buy the cheapest cell phone with a big enough screen which some knowledgeable friend of sales rep recommends; and then again keep it until it falls apart. (And if willpower and perseverance can only be increased with effort we are in a vicious circle, aren't we? Because only wily and perseverant people will put in the effort.)

Comment: The problem here is that it  is very subjective, and the only true answer would be the likes of "yes, but also no". You're talking about individuals here, and while some people can't sleep if their cellphone is not the latest model (the likes which would probably have an obsession with gaining more mana) others are happy with the good old phone they've had for 5 years and still does all they need it to (the kind that'd only invest until they have enough mana to power the spells they use, and then stop). This question is simply way too broad to be answered properly.

Comment: For everyone concerned: I just edited.  I hope it's better now.

Answer (score 1):

The need for will manifests during direct confrontation. Will makes a mage strong. Two mages in a contest of will should remind you of the need for strength when arm wrestling.

However, a war is rarely won through arm wrestling. A mage is rarely sure whose will dominates. So direct confrontation is seldom favored over advantage seeking. Such is politics. This regulates demonstrations of will to exhibitions. Something to witness on fight night. It’s a relief after all that advantage seeking tension.